# Magento 2 programatically add product to cart?

Tags: magento2, product, addtocart, programmatically

We have a requirement that we wants to add product to cart programmatically in magento2.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
protected $formKey;   
protected $cart;
protected $product;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
array $data = []) {
    $this->formKey = $formKey;
    $this->cart = $cart;
    $this->product = $product;      
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
 { 
  $productId =10;
  $params = array(
                'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                'product' => $productId, //product Id
                'qty'   =>1 //quantity of product                
            );              
    //Load the product based on productID   
    $_product = $this->product->load($productId);       
    $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
    $this->cart->save();
 }
```

Comment: Do we need to pass the customer id here?

Comment: no need @srg please place the 'code' in your custom controller and submit the form

Comment: so how can we identify the product is added to which customer cart?

Comment: ok let me check and update you, before that please try with the above code and comment me with u required details

Comment: @srg what exact scenario you want to add product to cart let me know so that i can give i better idea or suggestion thanks

Comment: the above code is adding product to guest cart  succesfully. can you help me to add product to a registered customer cart using customer id  or something like that?

Comment: Please confirm in your requirement whether the customer has been logged in or not for performing this task? if he logged-in automatically that cart item has been assigned to the particular customer. Any way let me recheck and  update for you. thanks

Comment: @Nagaraju Kasa How to add configurable product to cart with product option in magento2?

Comment: how are you amith actually i didn't try i will try and post you answer have you checked any references?

Comment: please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182996/magento2-how-to-add-configurable-product-to-cart-programmatically

Comment: This code to add in controller or block?

Comment: @ramesh we need to add in Controller

Comment: The class `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart` is marked as deprecated. Is there een alternative?

Comment: how do we know product has been added to cart or not ?

Comment: you can see that item whether added  in the  minicart  right ?

Comment: @Michiel Just use `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote instead`

Comment: its doesn't work for minicart and checkout/cart.

Comment: @NagarajuKasa, i am trying to get quoteid after addtocart, it is getting as empty,here is my full question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274172/quote-id-not-getting-when-inserting-multiple-records-in-to-cart-in-magento2