# Magento 2 how to add products into cart without loading page

Tags: magento2, addtocart

[image]Magento 2 how to add products into the cart without loading page and I need to check every time quantity in DB and after adding the product into cart the product quantity must be reduced and check it

Comment: can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: you can add product to cart using programming, you need to used those things.

Comment: You can find your answer here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190369/magento-2-programatically-add-product-to-cart. If you don't want to reload the page, do it using ajax

Comment: As when i add product to mini cart page its taking onload(loading) and then its adding product. As my req is that when we add product to mini cart it must check quantity in db and must add. Product quantity in backend is1 and if we select 2 quantity in frontend then input box must be disable.because i am using  Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart concept

Answer (score 0):

add with in script

{
       "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
           "catalogAddToCart": {
              "bindSubmit": true
            }
       }
   }