# Magento 2 Addtocart Group product programatically

Tags: magento2, addtocart, programmatically, grouped-products

I am facing the **problem** with the **Addtocart** group product. Can anyone suggest me the code? I have tried as a simple product but it's **not working** as well try with below code but that did not work out for me.

```
  $params = array('product' => $key,'super_group' => $super_group);
```

Can anyone please suggest the format of addtocart group product. 
Thank you in Advanced

Comment: Follow this code and customize based on your requirement : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/243628/

Comment: but for the group product, there is a super_group option instead of super_attribute. Is this code will workout for group product addtocart?

Comment: Please follow this code:
[https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/190371/84493](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/190371/84493) Hope it solve your problem.

Comment: This solution will work for only simple products. As I know that for group product have different parameters