# magento 2.2.2 You need to choose options for your item

Tags: magento2, php, configurable-product, addtocart, attribute-options

I want to add a configurable products to cart via ajax, for this I have tried below code but it always raised the error **“You need to choose options for your item”**.

> Code

```
public function execute() {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $quote = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
        $productId = 20318;
        $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);

        $cart = $objectManager->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
        $params = array();

        $options = array(
            "194" => "445",
            "202" => "447",
            "193" => "416",
            "201" => "439",
            "197" => "430",
            "196" => "427",
        );
        $params['qty'] = 1;
        $params['product'] = 20318;

        $params['super_attribute'] = $options;


        $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
        $cart->save();
    }
```

Can anyone please let me know whats the issue?

I have also tried the below code but it raised the same error. 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/198818/38685
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/183836/38685

Comment: do not use the objectmanager it's bad practice

Comment: @PhilippSander okay I will remove that. but can you please let  me know whats wrong in my error and how to solve this error?

Comment: please try building the options array with ints instead of strings

Comment: we don't know the product. maybe there's actually an option missing

Comment: @PhilippSander I have tried this too but same error

Comment: @PhilippSander no option missing I have tried by passing the child Id too. but same error

Comment: you will have to debug this. we can't help you with the information you provided. do other products work like this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90602/discussion-between-narayan-and-philipp-sander).